# update incremental values into an SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for some help with the following query:

I have a bunch of rows with column TYPE, VERSION - however in some cases the version got messed up so I want to rewrite it.

Basically, it now looks this:

```
Type, Version
A, 0
A, 0
A, 1
A, 2
B, 1
B, 3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Type, Version
A, 0
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 0
B, 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: How do you know which "A , 0" record should become "A , 1"? If you have a reliable way to order these the solution will be much easier.

Comment: Either one will do, as I can't know for sure which A is truly the earlier version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Version) - 1 AS V
FROM YourTable       
)
UPDATE T 
SET Version = V
```

Comment: +1 - I missed the `-1` at the end of the ROW_NUMBER() when I posted my comment.

Comment: @JNK - It wasn't there then. I noticed the start at zero just after posting.